# Constraining dynamic sized views to bottom of a view in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a layout with design requirement like :

[image: Large TV]

The close button has to be on top, and below it are the `ImageView` and `TextView`. The `TextView`'s size is dynamic, depending on what was saved in the database. Both `ImageView` and `TextView` has to be below close button like the first image, and :

[image: Small TV]

If it were the other way around, I can just use `Barrier` with `bottom` direction and refer the ids of `ImageView` and `TextView` for the close button to position itself to, but it's the other way around now.

Is there any way to do this view without nesting `ImageView` and `TextView` in another layout, say, `LinearLayout`? Trying to achieve non nested views as I am using `ConstraintLayout`..

Thanks in advance!

EDIT :

Here's a testlayout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/waste_type_close"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_account_alert_grey600_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/waste_type_image"
        android:layout_width="84dp"
        android:layout_height="84dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_account_alert_black_48dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/waste_type_close" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/waste_type_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:text="name"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"            
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/waste_type_image"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/waste_type_image"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/waste_type_image" />

</ConstraintLayout>
```

EDIT :

This is another testlayout :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/waste_type_close"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_account_alert_grey600_24dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/waste_type_barrier"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/waste_type_image"
    android:layout_width="84dp"
    android:layout_height="84dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_account_alert_black_48dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/waste_type_close" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/waste_type_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:text="nameaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/waste_type_image"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/waste_type_image"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/waste_type_image" />

<android.support.constraint.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/waste_type_barrier"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierDirection="top"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="waste_type_image, waste_type_name"/>
```

Which yields :

[image: Barrier test]

Comment: what is the problem of setting the barrier ?

Answer (score 0):

Placing a barrier constrained to below close button and placing a constraint where below items(imageview and textview) are constrained to the bottom of the barrier should do it.  For the dynamic textview just create a constraint on Imageview with respect to start of textview.

Comment: CMIIW, but isn't putting a barrier referencing only 1 item is the same as just constraining one of the below items? About the dynamic `TV`, I need to make it `center_vertical`-like with the `IV`.. I haven't tried using two top constraint tho, let me try it in just a sec - Edit : Yeah it doesn't work, Imma post a test layout, to make it easier for people to try

Comment: Yes, that means the two views would "stick" to the barrier right? I need it to be `center_vertical` :\

Comment: center_vertical with respect to the barrier and parent_bottom?

Comment: Nope, imagine the two views are in a `LinearLayout` with `center_vertical` as its gravity, then the `LinearLayout` has `layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/waste_type_close`. This is what I wanna achieve, but without the `LinearLayout`. I should put this in the question too

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this layout is not possible using only a `ConstraintLayout` with three children.

Despite the fact that "the point" of ConstraintLayout is to avoid nested views, sometimes that's the only way to get what you want. Here, I think you should wrap `waste_type_image` and `waste_type_name` in a `LinearLayout`.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/waste_type_close"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete_24dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/waste_type_close"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/waste_type_image"
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="84dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share_24dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/waste_type_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="name"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
```

Comment: "sometimes that's the only way to get what you want".. This is so sad.. Alexa play Despacito :(.. I have been using this layout too before I asked the question, and fiddled with it.. Well, then until the answer is found, I should keep using this for now..

Comment: The problem is that you need two "top" constraints for two of your views: you need top/bottom of `waste_type_image` and `waste_type_name` to constrain to the top/bottom of each other (so you get the vertical centering), but you also need the top of both to constrain to the bottom of `waste_type_close` (so you get them below the close image)... and ConstraintLayout just can't do that.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, if only `group` can do this kind of thing.. It only knows how to set visibility on its views

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SequenceLayout](https://github.com/yasharpm/SequenceLayout) to achieve this.

There is already a sample there for a similar problem. (Check [Use Android's ConstraintLayout to create table-like view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55375635/use-androids-constraintlayout-to-create-table-like-view))

Following is how you get to do it:

```xml
<com.yashoid.sequencelayout.SequenceLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:pgSize="360"
    app:sequences="@xml/sequences">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/waste_type_close"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_account_alert_grey600_24dp"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/helper"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/waste_type_image"
        android:layout_width="84dp"
        android:layout_height="84dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_account_alert_black_48dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/waste_type_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="name"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</com.yashoid.sequencelayout.SequenceLayout>
```

Your `@xml/sequences` will be like this:

```xml
<Sequences>
    <Horizontal>
        <Span size="1w"/>
        <Span id="@id/waste_type_close" size="24pg"/>
        <Span size="16pg"/>
    </Horizontal>

    <Horizontal>
        <Span size="36pg"/>
        <Span id="@id/waste_type_image" size="84pg"/>
        <Span size="12pg"/>
        <Span id="@id/waste_type_name" size="1w"/>
        <Span size="16pg"/>
    </Horizontal>

    <Vertical>
        <Span size="20pg"/>
        <Span id="@id/waste_type_close" size="24pg"/>
        <Span size="16pg"/>
        <Span id="@id/helper" size="@MAX(100%waste_type_image,100%waste_type_name)"/>
    </Vertical>

    <Vertical start="start@helper" end="end@helper">
        <Span size="1w"/>
        <Span id="waste_type_image" size="84pg"/>
        <Span size="1w"/>
    </Vertical>

    <Vertical id="waste_type_name_sequence" start="start@helper" end="end@helper">
        <Span size="1w"/>
        <Span id="waste_type_name" size="wrap"/>
        <Span size="1w"/>
    </Vertical>
</Sequences>
```